# Android Mediacodec encode h264 and decode in different platforms (Android,iOS, Web)

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, h.264, android-mediacodec

I am developing an Android app `(min sdk=21)` which required to stream real-time video(capture from an Android device camera) to different platform(Android/IOS/web).
I decided to use Media codec to encode the video to h.264 and send the raw data by `TCP socket` to other devices.

I created an input surface from Media codec and I set the color format to `MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface`.

Android devices should be able to decode this raw data, but is it possible to ***decode this raw data in iOS or Web*** if I choose this color format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the input color type shouldn't matter. Even if you use `COLOR_FormatSurface`, it still is encoded as a normal YUV 4:2:0 video as if you'd use the other, non-surface color formats.

If you'd manually choose a more uncommon color format like YUV 4:4:4 (when not using surface input), the encoder could either choose to actually downsample this into YUV 4:2:0 (and all decoders would support it) or keep it as is and encode into the more uncommon variants of H264, which not all decoders might be able to decode.

Comment: thx for your help, I can now successfully encode and decode in few Android Devices. However, I got a new problem. When I put my app to NanoPi m3(Android 5.0), it cannot encode correctly. The output size from encoder only got 11 bytes in each frame. Any idea about this?